# Show on hover issue

Tags: vb.net, winforms

So I have a simple form with a button on it.  On the form's MouseEnter event I am setting the button to visible.  On the form's MouseLeave event I'm setting the button to hidden.  In effect, only when you hover over the form should the button be seen.  The problem is that when you put the cursor over the button it disappears.  Even if the button is directly in the center of the form it still exhibits this same behavior.

Is there a solution other than putting MouseEnter/Exit events on the button and everything else inside the form?

```
Public Class VerticalStrip
    Private Sub VerticalStrip_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        btnAdd.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub VerticalStrip_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseEnter
        btnAdd.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub VerticalStrip_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseLeave
        btnAdd.Visible = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; in the `MouseLeave` event, first check if the mouse has in fact left the form:

```
Public Class VerticalStrip
    Private Sub VerticalStrip_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        btnAdd.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub VerticalStrip_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseEnter
        btnAdd.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub VerticalStrip_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseLeave
        If Not Me.ClientRectangle.Contains(Me.PointToClient(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position)) Then
            btnAdd.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```